# Trying to create a custom font-size attribute in html and pass it to CSS

Tags: html, css, attributes

I am trying to create a custom font-size attribute in html where the value I assign to the attribute is passed to the CSS file but it does not seem to be working

HTML:

```
<h1 fsize="4rem">TEST</h1>
```

CSS:

```
h1::after {
    font-size: attr(fsize);
}
```

I am trying to do it without using any classes, or style tags

Comment: This seems like a solved problem, given `data-*` and `style` attributes, along with custom CSS properties; why do you need to reinvent that wheel with invalid html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want attribute then you need javascript (at least in 2022)

---

but for now, you can do it with `CSS vars` (CSS only)

> more details here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties

Support is pretty good, including Edge (but no IE) **96.61%** https://caniuse.com/?search=var()

[image]

```css
h1::after {
  content: "hello world";
  font-size: var(--fsize);
}
```

```html
<h1 style="--fsize: 2rem;"></h1>
<h1 style="--fsize: 5rem;"></h1>
<h1 style="--fsize: 10rem;"></h1>
<h1 style="--fsize: 3rem;"></h1>
```

---

#### still want the attribute?

```js
function styleFsize() {
  const ATTR_NAME = "fsize";
  const allEl = document.querySelectorAll(`[${ATTR_NAME}]`);
  allEl.forEach(el => {
    el.style.setProperty(`--${ATTR_NAME}`, el.getAttribute(`${ATTR_NAME}`));
  })
}

styleFsize();
```

```css
h1::after {
  content: "hello world";
  font-size: var(--fsize);
}
```

```html
<h1 fsize="10rem"></h1>
<h1 fsize="5rem"></h1>
<h1 fsize="2rem"></h1>
<h1 fsize="1rem"></h1>
```

---

> **note**:
>
>  if you want a valid HTML attribute...
>
> you need to use `data-NAME_ATTRIBUTE`
>
>  so it will become `data-fsize`
>
> by doing so now you can do
>
>  ✅ `el.dataset.fsize` instead of ❌ `el.getAttribute("fsize")`

Answer (score 0):

`attr` works only for content in most (?all) browsers at the moment.

You can use a CSS variable instead. i.e. have a style attribute rather than an fsize attribute. No need for further style tags.

```css
h1::after {
  font-size: var(--fsize);
  content: 'I am the content of the after pseudo element';
}
```

```html
<h1 style="--fsize:4rem;">TEST</h1>
```

Note: if you do ever want to use your own attribute then it should start with data-